# map state in return React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

[image][image]

why am I not getting any numbers return in my state array with react map function?

```
        {
          this.state.studentAssignment.map(student=>{
            return(<Row className="maxi">
              {
                student.map(s=>{
                  return(
                    <Col sm={1} md={2}>{s}</Col>
                  )
                })
              }
              </Row>
            )
          })
        }
```

Comment: Don't use `map` when you don't want to return anything. Use `forEach`instead. It is a surprisingly common source of bugs

Comment: Im not even getting anything if I use forEach

Comment: `forEach` is for the scenario where you don't return values from your callback function. Either you meant to return from your `map` callback where you should be using `forEach` so that your code isn't confusing

Answer (score 2):

[Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) should always return value when used, your code is not returning any value, just add `return s;` after the `console.log()`:

```
{
  this.state.studentAssignment.map(student=>{
    return(
      student.map(s=> { console.log(s); return s });
    );
  })
}
```

Comment: I add the code on it, and I return it. edit my post. 

So it might not be the return problem? cause I have 2 number value that couldn't retreive

Comment: Your code should be fine and  return result, can you create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) snippet to reproduce the issue?

Comment: here is an example of your code in codesandbox, try to reproduce it and I will help you debugging/fixing it: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-allen-43l6z?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, it's working fine. Please check after providing key to each item in map.
Here's the codesandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-perlman-ofu8j?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
{
            this.state.studentAssignment.map((student, index) => {
              return (<Row className="maxi" key={index}>
                {
                  student.map((s, i) => {
                    return (
                      <Col sm={1} md={2} key={i}>{s}</Col>
                    )
                  })
                }
              </Row>
              )
            })
          }
```